# If you know a man's name, can you still call him "sir"?

Tags: word-meaning

If it's acceptable, is it done out of respect?

Comment: It can be done respectfully, and it can be done sarcastically. It depends on the circumstances and how it is said.

Answer (score 1):

*Sir*
is used as a formal and polite way of speaking to a man, especially one who is in a position of authority:

> "Did you hear what I said?" "Yes, Sir."

It can be used as an ironic or humorous title of respect: sir critic.

> " Excuse me, sir critic, but that is none of your business."